# How to get the rolling amount of last three months based on my period code in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am summarizing distinct count of players for each month but i don't know how to get the rolling three months for each month.

Below is my current dax on power bi

```
Summary_Dis_Player = ADDCOLUMNS(

     SUMMARIZE(

          playerdaily,

          playerdaily[MonthRolNo]
     ),

     "Distinct Player",CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(playerdaily[Name])

)

)
```

output

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a calendar table? for this sort of time intelligence it would help

Comment: Yes I do. I attached in the post above.